# Powershell: modifying text

Tags: powershell

ok, I give up! why doesn't this work? Im just trying to loop through a csv file and replace any value in the nth column with some value.

```
$source = "C:\blah.csv"

(gc $source) | foreach{ $_.Split(',')[10] = 'something'} | sc $source
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do and what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: In particular, do you know the name of the field which value you are trying to replace or is it only its index (10) known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you are trying is something like that:

```
$s = 'a,b,c,d,e'
$s.Split(',')[4] = 'something'
$s
```

That won't work, because you don't assign 'something' to any variable.

I would either read the file as csv (via `Import-CSV`) or (if it structure is really simple) use regexes:

```
$s = 'c,d,e', 'c,d,x', 'z,f,d'
$s | % { $_ -replace '(?<=([^,]*,){2}).*','something'}
```

Comment: I wonder if he is trying to compare against 'something' and should be using `-eq`?

Comment: @Keith, for me it makes more sense to replace some value. But you might be right. Peter didn't tell us what he wanted to do.

Comment: @Peter, look at e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx Just read it as csv and ... (it's up to you) ;)